# Loading stories from classpath (and stories aren't called .story)

Tags: java, jbehave

I have a multi-module maven project. My story files are in a module of their own, because we have separate gui and api tests driven from them, and a jar is created containing these -- the story files are named `*.feature`.

In another module I have created a `Story` class:

```
  public class NewAnnouncements extends JUnitStory {
    @Override
    public Configuration configuration() {
      return new MostUsefulConfiguration().useStoryLoader(new LoadFromClasspath());
    }

    @Override
    public InjectableStepsFactory stepsFactory() {
        return new InstanceStepsFactory(configuration(), new NewAnnouncements());
    }
  }
```

But, predictably, this does not find its stories. How could it? The stories aren't called *.story and they aren't on the filesystem (though they are in the same classpath). The error I get is:

```
org.jbehave.core.io.StoryResourceNotFound: Story path 'org/.../announcement/new_announcements.story' not found by class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@63e68a2b
```

How do I get jbehave to find my story files? How do I make it understand that they're not called `*.story`?

Comment: I have read the jbehave documentation and that doesn't help at all as most examples seem to be loading from the filesystem. I have googled the issue too, and that also doesn't help primarily for the same reason.

Comment: http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/reporting-stories.html#highlighter_858005

Comment: @BackSlash - Thanks for the link, but I don't see how it relates to the problem at hand. Can you expand a little?

Comment: Please read it: The text before the second codeblock (the little one), says: _The builder provides defaults for all the formats supported,_ ***but if the user needs to create a bespoke instance of a reporter for a given format, it can be easily done by overriding the default. E.g. to override the reporter for TXT format to use a ".text" extension***. After that there is an example on how to work with `.text` extension (which you can adapt to your extension)

Comment: Again, thanks, and I have read it, but I'm not looking to create a reporter (yet) -- I'm trying to locate the stories in order to run my tests at all. Right now, I don't have anything to report. Is my question unclear on this point? Should I update it?

Answer (score 0):

Try an example from JBehave documentation with JUnitStories :
http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/configuration.html

```
public class TraderStories extends JUnitStories {

public TraderStories() {
    // configure as TraderStory except for
    Configuration configuration = new MostUsefulConfiguration()
            .useStoryLoader(new LoadFromURL())
}

@Override
protected List<String> storyPaths() {
    String codeLocation = codeLocationFromClass(this.getClass()).getFile();
    return new StoryFinder().findPaths(codeLocation, asList("**/trader*.story"),
                asList(""), "file:"+codeLocation);
}
```

and replace in this example the pattern: `asList("**/trader*.story")` 
with a pattern: `asList("**/*.feature")`